# Saving output of whos command into a file

Tags: save, octave

How to save output of whos command into a file in Octave. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Do you just want the printed output or do you want *all* of the data (i.e. the data you get when you assign the output to a variable: `data = whos;`?

Comment: @Suever: I just wanted to store the content into a file that is displayed when we call whos command. Using diary command allowed what i was expecting. Thanks for showing interest. I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the screen output, the [diary](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Diary-and-Echo-Commands.html) can be useful.

The following commands would save the `whos` output in a file named "whos_output.txt".

```
diary("whos_output.txt")
whos
diary off
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It worked out for me.